# how to disable multiple options if one option is selected in the forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Hello is there any way to disable multiple options in a select form if you only choose one option?

For example:

First Select Form

```
<select name="secondchoice" id="second">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="Content Dev">Content Dev</option>
<option value="Web">Web</option>
<option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Managing">Managing</option>
</select>
```

Second Select Form

```
<select name="day2" id="exam2">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
</select>
```

If I select "None" in the first form then the second form must disable the options "Monday-Thursday" the only option available must be also "None" in the second form. Thank you!

Comment: post a [mcve] with JavaScript/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript by hiding options in the second elements whenever the first select element changes by checking its value and hiding elements accordingly like so:

```js
// Select Elements
const first = document.getElementById('first')
const second = document.getElementById('second')

// Option Elements
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const two = document.getElementById('two')

// Runs whenever first select has changed
first.onchange = () => {
  // Checks First Selects Value
  if (first.value === '1') {
    // If '1' then hide TWO and show ONE
    second.value = 'ONE'
    one.hidden = false
    two.hidden = true
  } else if (first.value === '2') {
    // Else, if '2' then hide ONE and show TWO
    second.value = 'TWO'
    one.hidden = true
    two.hidden = false
  }
}
```

```html
<select id='first'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id='second'>
  <option id='one'>ONE</option>
  <option id='two'>TWO</option>
</select>
```

This is a very basic example and can be improved alot.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below, so when you do selecting none, other options would be disabled, and other than none it would be enabled again

```
function disabledEnabled(event) {
  var optiosLists = document.getElementById("exam2").options;
    
        
        for (let i = 0; i < optiosLists.length; i++) {
             if(event.target.value === "None"){                 
                 optiosLists[i].disabled = true;        
                  optiosLists[0].disabled = false;
                } else {
                    optiosLists[i].disabled = false;    
                }
            
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: yes, thanks for let this know, will update and care from next time

Answer (score 0):

You can either `disabled` select element itself and each of its options. You can find 2 ways to achieve each of those below.

- [Disabling Select Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp)
- [Disabling Option Element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp)